# How to set a date column as NULL in Parse.com with REST API?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, parse-platform, titanium

I have a custom field of datatype date. I am trying to reset / remove the datetime value and set it to Null / blank / default 00... using REST API.

However, all my attempts so far have resulted in error. Here is how my JSON looked like in various attempts...

```
   {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": NULL
    } ;

   {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": ""
    } ;

   {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "0000-00-00T00:00:00.000Z"
    } ;
```

Any guidance or tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
object.unset("columnName")
```

object: is the Parse Object

"columName": is the name of column you want to set NULL

refer [link](https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-set-a-parsefile-column-to-null)